# MatLab : Read Arduino's Serial Monitor

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port, text-files

How to display what's shown inside an Arduino's Serial Monitor , in a MATLab program? From Arduino we can display the output via serial monitor using **serial.println** and **serial.print**. But how to display the **serial.println** and **serial.print** from arduino inside MATlab? If in Qt programming, anything can be shown in QDebug, but I really don't know how it goes for MATLab.

Maybe just a simple **serial.println('1')** to show the character '1' in the serial monitor. Then, how can we program the MATLAB to read/detect the '1' and do something about it, such as.... creating a simple textfile?

Can anyone please teach me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we are going to close the eventually open port:

```
%% Port reset:
delete(instrfindall);
```

Then you have to open a communication with your arduino (check your arduino IDE to know which port is selected). Also select the right BaudRate.

```
%% Serial open
arduino=serial('COM4','BaudRate',9600);
```

Then you can start to read the arduino output. Let's say that we want to read the 10 first outputs. (so the 10 first serial.printxx)

```
%% Start to read arduino's values and write the result in results.txt
fopen(arduino)
fid = fopen('results.txt','wt');
for i=1:10
    y = fscanf(arduino,'%s');
    fprintf(fid,'my arduino output is %s\n',y)
end
fclose(fid);
fclose(arduino);
```

Matlab will read the arduino value as a string, I let you cast this string into whatever you need.

**IMPORTANT:**

You need to install the [arduino support package](https://ch.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-matlab.html) for matlab

**ADVICE**

I usually read the output using an endless while loop that check on every step if the loop need to be skipped.

For example if your arduino code send a `Serial.println('exit')`

my matlab code will look like:

```
while 1
    y = fscanf(arduino,'%s');
    if strcmp(y,'exit')
       break
    end 
    fprintf('my arduino output is %s\n',y)
end
```